# Why is this error of convertion type SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I create a table like

```
CREATE TABLE #tab(ID INT,Value FLOAT)
```

inside a loop (`@n` is counter)I insert elements dynamicaly:

SET @sql = 'INSERT #tab(ID,Value) SELECT '+@n+', SUM('+@x+'*'+@y+') FROM '+ @table_name;
when attempt to execute this:

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'INSERT #tab  (ID,Value) SELECT ' to data type int.
```

I don't understand why it says convertion, as id is defined as INT.

How do you fix this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [CAST function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

```
'SELECT '+ CAST(@n AS VARCHAR) +', SUM('+@x+'*'+@y+') FROM '
```

The error happened because you try to join a `CHAR` with a `INT`. The `CHAR` in this case is the *'SELECT '* string.